# How to use maxlength = 20 validation in form fields using selenium webdriver

Tags: validation, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

The form has three fields
1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Phone

I want max 20 characters length validation in name fields.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. We prefer it if you show us what you've tried. Also, Selenium is a web testing system. It doesn't do form validation, though it might verify it. Are you looking to test or enforce this validation?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of verifying validations of fields.

If user try to enter more than max limit in field

1. It prevents user to enter text and turns the color of field to red
2. It allows more text to field and shows validation message when try to do form submission or move to next field.

Solution:

Using sendKeys() method send more than 20 characters to field,

Case 1: 
1. Get text of the same field using getText() method, then perform String.length and perform Assert to make sure character count is 20

2. Then verify CSS property of field and make sure color turns to red using Assert.

Case 2: Perform case 1 first point,
then get locator of validation message and get text from it and verify with expected validation message.

Answer (score 0):

Enter more than 20 characters using selenium web driver in textbox and then get the text of the same textbox using selenium and calculate the length of the string it should be 20 and not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

To check the maximum and minimum length of any field, you can use the HTML's `maxlength` and `minlength` attribute and then find the length using Selenium's `getAttribute("maxlength")` and `getAttribute("minlength")` function.

Sample code is given below: Say we're talking about the username field.

```
//Getting the minimum and maximum value of the username field
int minLengthDefined = Integer.parseInt(mcp.userName().getAttribute("minlength"));
int maxLengthDefined = Integer.parseInt(mcp.userName().getAttribute("maxlength"));

//Get the typed value
String typedValue = mcp.userName().getAttribute("value");

//Get the length of the typed value
int size = typedValue.length();

if( size < minLengthDefined ){
    Assert.assertEquals(size, minLengthDefined, "Username field has incorrect value.");
    Sysout.out.println("It contains "+size+" characters.");
    Sysout.out.println("Username should lie between "+minLengthDefined+ " and "+maxLengthDefined+ " characters." );
}
else if( size > maxLengthDefined) {
    Assert.assertEquals(size, maxLengthDefined, "Username field has incorrect value.");
    Sysout.out.println("It contains "+size+" characters.");
    Sysout.out.println("Username should lie between "+minLengthDefined+ " and "+maxLengthDefined+ " characters." );
}
else
    Sysout.out.println("unhandled issue occurred!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to validate minimum and maximum character length of some text field.
Here is a code snippet to get the email field minimum and maximum character length and to validate it, hope i answered your question :)

First get the HTML attribute minlength and maxlength for your required field.

public class LoginPage{

@FindBy(name = "email")
WebElement txtEmail;

public int[] getEmailMinMaxCharLength() {

```
    int[] charLength = new int[2];
    charLength[0] = Integer.parseInt(txtEmail.getAttribute("minlength"));
    charLength[1] = Integer.parseInt(txtEmail.getAttribute("maxlength"));
    return charLength;

}
```

}

public class Test{

LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();

@Test
public void verifyMinMaxCharLength() {

```
    int[] charlength = loginPage.getEmailMinMaxLength();
    int minCharLength = charlength[0];
    int maxCharLength = charlength[1];

    softAssert.assertEquals(minCharLength, 5);
    softAssert.assertEquals(maxCharLength, 50);
    softAssert.assertAll();
}
```

}